# Searching for JDK equivalent for transforming while collecting stream

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream, collectors

## Problem

I have a `List` of `Request` objects, where each request contains the origin host and the requested URL. I want to transform this into `Map<String, Set<String>>`, where the keys are the hosts and the values are the unique URLs that have been called by the host.

### My own solution

I found that you could use `Collectors.groupingBy` to transform a `List` into a `Map`. This seemed like the method for the job, but it didn't fit my total needs. I had to create an extra function:

```
    private static <T, K> Collector<T, ?, Set<K>> toSet(Function<? super T, ? extends K> mapper) {
        return Collector.of(
                HashSet::new,
                (list, item) -> list.add(mapper.apply(item)),
                (list1, list2) -> {
                    list1.addAll(list2);
                    return list1;
                }
        );
    }
```

Using this function, I could do it like this:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> hostUrls = getRequests().stream()
    .map(r -> new ImmutablePair<>(r.getOriginHost(), r.getRequestUrl()))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ImmutablePair::getLeft, toSet(ImmutablePair::getRight)));
```

### Question

Is there some way to do this transforming without creating this extra `toSet` function?

My wish doesn't seem that extreme. I want some extra kind of mapping before collecting everything into one `Set` (could also be any other kind of collection of course). I have the feeling that I am missing some function, but I cannot see which.

Comment: You can do like this: `getRequests().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Request::getOriginHost,Collectors.mapping(Request::getRequestUrl,Collectors.toSet()));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to define any extra method. You can perform `Collectors.mapping` after `groupingBy` as below.

`Collectors.mapping` has two arguments. first is a mapper and the second is downstream.

```
 Collector<T, ?, R> mapping(Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper,
                               Collector<? super U, A, R> downstream)
```

By using `toSet` downstream you can complete your task.

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map = getRequests().stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Request::getOriginHost,
                 Collectors.mapping(Request::getRequestUrl, Collectors.toSet())));
```